# Command line ODBCCONF CONFIGDSN database name containing Pipe (broken bar) characters

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, command-line, odbc

I am trying to use the following command line command to change the database my ODBC connection is connected to. The problem is, the names of all the databases on my server contain this character `|` — the result is the code you see below. I am getting an error that says "Invalid Keyword-value pairs".

```
ODBCConf CONFIGDSN "SQL Server" "DSN=dsnName|database=dbname | dbNameContinued | dbNameContinued | dbNameEnd"
```

If I try this

```
ODBCConf CONFIGDSN "SQL Server" "DSN=dsnName|database="dbname | dbNameContinued | dbNameContinued | dbNameEnd""
```

It still doesn't work

Any help here would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

It kinda does something when I do this:

```
"DSN=myDSNname|Server=myServerName|Trusted_Connection=Yes|da‌​tabase="dbNameStart ^| dbNameCont ^| dbNameCont ^| dbNameEnd""
```

So maybe now it's the spaces? Because now I'm just getting a name that looks like: "dbNameStart"; there is nothing after the first space.

Comment: Why do your database names have broken bars in the name?  Just to make sure life is as hard as possible for everyone?  My strong recommendation would be to stick with regular ASCII alphanumerics and maybe underscore (perhaps dash or dot too) in the name.  Follow the KISS principle.  (If you can't change them, you'll have to get someone else to chime in with information on how to work around the bad design.  Good luck!)

Comment: Unfortunately that is just the way we have them set up (not by my design) and we have A LOT of databases so I really don't want to have to change them all

Comment: In command line, a caret(^) should be the right escape character.

Comment: Maybe you need to use a caret before each space too.

Comment: Tried didn’t work :/